# Showing an animated GIF using GMSGroundOverlay

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsgroundoverlay

I am trying to display an animated GIF over a specific part of a GMSMapView, using GMSCoordinateBounds to designate the part of the map to overlay the GIF on.

I'm choosing to use GMSGroundOverlay because I want the image to scale properly when the map is zoomed in or out, and to have the image remain fixed to one geographical part of the map. This seems to be the best tool to accomplish this task.
I found that GMSMarkers could display GIFs, but I would also need the GIF to be able to scale up and down as the map is zoomed, which GMSMarkers seem incapable of doing by themselves.

Currently, while I can swap between images by changing the icon attribute of the GMSGroundOverlay to simulate animation, because I am working with 24 images that are downloaded, this solution is not ideal due to increased file sizes.
I tried using UIImage's animatedImageWithImages:duration: to set the icon using the following:

```
let icon = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(centroidImagesAtLayer, duration: animationSpeed)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWestBound, coordinate: northEastBound)
centroidOverlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: bounds, icon: icon)
```

However, this only shows a singular static image. I found that UIImageView has functionality to animate images, using functions such as startAnimating(), so I'm wondering if this could lead to a solution in which a GIF can be displayed on a GMSGroundOverlay. I thought I could add my own UIImageView to the overlay myself. However, I feel I've hit a dead end, as I'm unable to figure out how the GMSGroundOverlay's UIimage, *icon*, is added to the overlay in the first place. I'm not sure how it's possible to add a UIImage to an NSObject, which is is what GMSGroundOverlay ultimately is subclassing.

I would really appreciate some suggestions on animating a GIF over a map, ideally using a GMSGroundOverlay using only a singular GIF file, and having that GIF scale and move on the screen properly as the user moves the map around. Thanks!